# PythonのIDLEでRun Moduleを実行するとinvalid syntaxとなってしまう

Tags: python, python-idle

初歩的な質問です。最初にHello World!と入力してRun Moduleをするとinvalid syntaxとなった後に、3.7.3の真ん中の7が赤く塗られます。これはどうやったら解決できますか？その先へ進めません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

補足
Windowsのpython IDLEです。
IDLEを開いて、入力した画面では上のバーのところにRunがなかったので、保存したやつを新たに開いて、Run→Run ModuleとやったらErrorが出ました。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらの画面は、Windowsで動かしているPython IDLEでしょうか？　「Run Module」は、このウィンドウの画面のメニュー「Run」から選択して動かしたということでしょうか？　質問文下の「編集」から、どのような操作をなさるとエラーが出るのか、箇条書きで書いていただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: 前の方が書かれているように、もう少し、情報があれば、回答が得られると思います。hello_world.py は、短いと想像しますが、それを提示されると回答が得られると思います。たぶん、print文の次のsyntaxがおかしいのだと思います。

Comment: （重複らしいので、こっちにも、コメントします。）7の背景が赤になっているのは、それほど、意味がないと想像します。意味があれば、もう少し、親切な表示がされると思います。(1)hello_world.pyの中身を示せますか？(2)コマンドプロンプトから、pythonを起動して、hello_world.pyを実行するとどうなりますか？　想像では、全角スペースとか、何かの都合で、syntax errorになっていると思うのですが。。。　　あと、プロンプト（>>>)からカーソルが1行進んでいるのに、原因が示されていると思います。

Answer (score 1):

画面が簡素すぎて分かりづらいですが、IDLEには「シェル ウィンドウ」と「エディタ ウィンドウ」の二つがあることを意識する必要があります。

---

**エラーの原因**

- IDLEの起動後は`>>>`でプロンプトが出ている通り、**シェルでの待ち受け状態**になっています。
- この画面で`print("Hello, World!")`と入力すると結果が表示され、再度入力待ちの状態になります。
- ここで File -> Save As で適当な名前を付けてファイルを保存します。
- 保存したファイルをメモ帳やテキストエディタで開くと、**IDLEの画面に表示されていた内容がそのまま**保存されています。
- 保存したファイルにはPythonのバージョン情報やプロンプト等の**余計な文字が含まれている**ので、このまま実行すると**Syntax Errorとなります**。

---

**正しい手順**

- スクリプトを記述するのであれば、IDLEを起動した後に File -> New File で**エディタ ウィンドウ**を開いてください (文字が何も表示されていない真っ白な状態)。
- ここに必要なPythonの記述、例えば`print("Hello, World!")`と入力し、ファイルを保存します。
- ここから Run Module を実行すれば、シェル ウィンドウ側でスクリプトが正常に実行されるはずです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます
シェルからSaveで保存すると上のものまでエディタに保存されるからシェルの上側+エディタウィンドウの上側でバージョン等の情報が被ってテキストエラーが起こると
とても分かりやすい説明でした

Answer (score 0):

確かにこちらでも同じ事が起こります

```
print("Hello world")
```

とだけ入力するのは特に特別な操作と言う訳では無いと思うのですが
windows10でPython3.7.4の64ビットを動かした際に
Shell時にはエンターキーでの動作が問題無くてもFileメニューのSaveで作ったpyではRunメニューからRun Moduleをすると構文エラーを吐きます
全角スペースについては見つからず、
一応Shellで試した場合のエラー表示と異なるようです
すみませんが、どのように解決したのか伺ってもよろしいでしょうか？