# orangeオブジェクトに腐る性質を追加するコードが書けません

Tags: python, python-idle

こんにちは！最近Pythonを学び始めた者です。参考書に載っている「orangeオブジェクトに腐る性質を追加するコード」を、載っている通りに書いているのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。
お力を貸していただけるとありがたいです。以下がそのコードです。

```py
class Orange:
    def __init__(self, w, c):
        self.weight = w
        self.color = c
        self.mold = 0
        print("Created!")

    def rot(self, days, temp):
        self.mold = days * temp

orange = Orange(200, "orange")
print(orange.mold)
orange.rot(10, 37)
print(orange.mold)
```

表示されたエラー

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#114>", line 1, in <module>
    orange.rot(10, 37)
AttributeError: 'Orange' object has no attribute 'rot'
```

Comment: 私の手元でそのコードを実行してみましたが、エラーにはなりませんでした。
エラーがでたファイルが`<pyshell#114>` とのことですが、後から `def rot(...)` メソッドを追加して、orangeのインスタンスを作り直していない、ということはないでしょうか？

Comment: `def rot()` の直前に空行が入っているため、pyshell ではメソッドではなく単なる関数定義として処理されているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: タグを見る限り IDLE を利用されていそうですが、IDLE 利用時の注意事項などを過去に投稿しているので参考にしてください。 - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/59035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純に、`def __init__(self, w, c):`と`def rot(self, days, temp):`の間の空行が、改行コードだけだからでしょう。
ここには4桁の空白文字を入れてから改行する必要があります。

4桁の空白文字の無い改行だと、`class Orange:`の定義がそこで終わってしまったものとみなされて、`class Orange:`と`def rot(self, days, temp):`は無関係な状態になります。

だいたい、質問のエラー以前にも、以下の様なエラーが発生しているはずなんですが。
IDLEでファイルを実行するのと、インタプリタに直接コードを入力するのとでは違うのでしょうかね。
以下は素のPythonを起動して入力した結果です。

```
>>> class Orange:
...     def __init__(self, w, c):
...         self.weight = w
...         self.color = c
...         self.mold = 0
...         print("Created!")
...
>>>     def rot(self, days, temp):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def rot(self, days, temp):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>         self.mold = days * temp
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    self.mold = days * temp
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
>>> orange = Orange(200, "orange")
Created!
>>> print(orange.mold)
0
>>> orange.rot(10, 37)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Orange' object has no attribute 'rot'
```

空白を含めた改行にすれば、以下のようになります。

```
>>> class Orange:
...     def __init__(self, w, c):
...         self.weight = w
...         self.color = c
...         self.mold = 0
...         print("Created!")
...
...     def rot(self, days, temp):
...         self.mold = days * temp
...
>>> orange = Orange(200, "orange")
Created!
>>> print(orange.mold)
0
>>> orange.rot(10, 37)
>>> print(orange.mold)
370
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

私の手元でそのコードを実行してみましたが、エラーにはなりませんでした。

エラーがでたファイルが`<pyshell#114>` とのことですが、後から `def rot(...)` メソッドを追加して、orangeのインスタンスを作り直していない、ということはないでしょうか？

`orange.py` 等のファイルにコードを書いて実行してみてください。